# cctype and mingw: ::isblank has not been declared

Tags: c++

I am trying to use ::isBlank from cctype in my mingw compiler. I have defined

```
_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_CTYPE_TR1
```

In order to enable the definition of ::isBlank and I also put it on c++14 standard in my compiler settings.

I am getting this error, however:

```
error: '::isblank' has not been declared.
```

I am trying to use SOL2.hpp (the single file version) and I cant do that without cctype appearantely.

Why is this happening?

--EDIT:--

I forgot to mention, the error brings me into the cctype header, which I did include properly

[image: proof]

Comment: `_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_CTYPE_TR1` is not for you to define. It is an internal libstdc++ macro. It is defined if the C runtime provided by your OS is up to the C99 standard. If it's not, there's very little you can do short of switching to a different OS.

Comment: I have an option that sets the gcc compiler to the c99 standard. Maybe this will work?

Comment: gcc is still using the Microsoft-provided runtime, so even with -std=c99 it ia using the c89 library on Windows (and thus isn't a true c99 compiler).

Comment: @n.m. Defining the define is a common fix for this problem that seemed to work for everyone but me.

Im using windows 8.1 64 bit. I find it hard to believe it doesnt support a 1999 standard. Also I am compiling in c++14, where it has been part of since c++11.

Comment: Microsoft didn't even try to support C99 until 2015 or so. Hard to believe but true.